# "time series" vs. "time-series"

Tags: hyphens

When "**time series**" is used as a **noun**, is a hyphen needed?

**a time-series** versus **a time series**

PS: I feel that when "**time series**" is used as an **adjective** (see below), a hyphen is needed to avoid ambiguity, but I am not so sure if a hyphen is needed when it is a noun.

**a time-series analysis** versus **a time series analysis**

Comment: To some extent it is a style choice. This will be local and specific to the place you want to publish.

Comment: Do you mean that the rule changes in each English-speaking country?

Comment: No I mean different offices (such as at book publishers or newspapers etc.) would have different style guides with different rules on what to hyphenate. You might even get things like two professors in the same university would disagree over which way was correct.

Comment: @pierrot5 I think it's more about which publication your text is to appear in rather than country. They may have their own style manual. Personally I've never used a hyphen.

Comment: It's a bit distracting to refer to *English-**speaking** countries* here, because this is purely a matter of orthography (the *written* form). Real language is *spoken*, and since those "potential" hyphens don't reflect anything in the spoken version, it doesn't really make any difference how you write it.

Answer (score 2):

All of the top search hits for 'time series analysis' see it written *without a hyphen*, and most of them seem scholarly references. Likewise, most references to a 'time series' are not hyphenated. I work in data analysis, and while I hadn't thought about the term too hard until now, I don't think I've ever seen it hyphenated.

If you've seen it written otherwise, it *could* be a style choice, or it could just as easily be considered a mistake - especially as most references are not hyphenated. Admittedly, there are no strict rules that govern when a compound noun should be hyphenated and examples are extremely inconsistent. But there seems no reason to hyphenate 'time series' - consider that 'TV series' is not normally hyphenated. Further, in the phrase 'time series analysis' there would be no benefit to hyphenate them - there is no reason to assume that the words 'series analysis' would be joined instead.